# Do I need to clean up service workers that will only be used once?

Tags: html, service-worker

I have a website that serves up the same page on every subdomain, i.e. `abc.example.com`, `xyz.example.com`, ... all serve up the same content. Each specific subdomain will only be accessed once by a given client (instead of `abc` or `xyz`, we're using guids)

The page being served up for each subdomain registers a service worker. This means that every subdomain will have a service worker registered for it. However once a client unloads the page, the service worker will never be used again since we never try to connect to the same subdomain again.

Do I need to try to clean up these unreachable service workers, or will browsers automatically handle this? If a client loads ten thousand of these unique subdomains over time for example, will this impact storage/perf? If I do need to clean up these service workers, how would I go about doing this when the page is unloaded?